# Invoke lambda for each object in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a big S3 Bucket (> 3 TB) containing only tens of thousands of small `data.txt` files with a hashed prefix like so:

```
uuid1/data.txt
uuid2/data.txt
uuid3/data.txt
...
```

where uuid is some unique id, for example `uuid1=hd73nv93ha7d`.

I also have a Lambda function that processes these `data.txt` files and saves the result in another s3 bucket. The Lambda function's only input argument ist the Key of the `data.txt`, e.g. `Key=uuid123/data.txt`.

What is the best way or service that loops through the bucket and triggers the lambda (concurrently) exactly once for each `data.txt` file?

Comment: Is "exactly once" a hard requirement? Is "at least once" not good enough?

Comment: You need to `ls` all objects in the bucket and then either invoke the lambda directly or put the message onto an sqs queue that then triggers the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [S3 inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to get the list of files in the S3 bucket into a file. Iterate through the list and call the Lambda using the appropriate SDK API. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property) is the JS function for invoking the Lambda.